# Zend GData, Google Calendar API Question

Tags: php, zend-gdata

I read the tutorial from IBM development website. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-googleclndr/#resources

I tested successfully. Now I don't know how to insert the **event Description** at my event view page. Based on the code below. Only showed event id, event title. Is there a parameter like **event->description** ? thanks.

The code below from the sample code file **view.php**

```
foreach ($feed as $event) {
  echo "<li>\n";
  echo "<h2>" . stripslashes($event->title) . "</h2>\n";
  echo stripslashes($event->summary) . " <br/>\n";
  $id = substr($event->id, strrpos($event->id, '/')+1);
  echo "<a href=\"edit.php?id=$id\">edit</a> | ";
  echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=$id\">delete</a> <br/>\n";
  echo "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is `$event->content`. Have a look at the [Manual for Zend_GData catelendar API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html).